# Finding a string in string, even if the match is off by a character

Tags: python, regex

Given a string/pattern, how would you search within a long sequence, for strings of the same length as the given pattern that match exactly or with a difference of one character?

For example: Looking for ATGG in "ATCGGGATTGGGG..."  --- you would find: **ATCG**GG**ATTG**GGG...

Also, I'd like know how to record the locations of these matches

Answer (score 0):

> for strings of the same length as the given pattern that match exactly or with a difference of one character?

For a toy example like this, the simplest approach is probably brute force: with a pattern like `ATGG|.TGG|A.GG|AT.G|ATG.`.

> how to record the locations of these matches

The match object returned by `re.match` or `re.search` (or in the iterator produced by `.finditer`; but *not* with `.findall` which just gives you the text of the matches) has a `.start` method that provides this information.